# How to make my lamp server accessible by others?

Tags: linux, localhost, centos7

I have downloaded the lamp stack server. I am using centos 7. When I put localhost:81/filename it is openeing but it is not working when viewed from other system.
My lamp uses port 81 so I changed Listen 81 in the httpd.conf and in the virtualhost as <virtualhost*:81>. But it is not working. Can anyone help me out this?

Answer (score 0):

Are the two systems already connected to each using a network device like a switch or router?

To share your server with another system , you must first connect both systems to the same network. After which you need to get the IP address assigned to the system hosting the server. On linux, you can type **ifconfig** command to get this address from the server system. Then enter address in other system like:

http://192.168.1.128/filename

to view the resource.

If you have a wireless wifi box or router, you can use it to connect both systems. Just switch on the box without connecting to the internet.

Connect both systems to the router. Then follow the steps cited above to connect both systems.

Comment: You are highly welcomed 